Checking that a morphism of schemes is an isomorphism
Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes locally of finite type over a field $k$, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of $k$-schemes.
It is known that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if for any $k$-scheme $S$, the induced map on $S$-points $$f(S): X(S) \to Y(S)$$ is a bijection, functorial in $S$.
My question is: in order to show that $f$ is an isomorphism, is it enough to show that the induced map $f(S)$ is a bijection, functorial in $S$, for all connected $k$-schemes $S$?

Instead of "functorial in $S$" you probably mean "natural in $S$". But this is satisfied anyway. Every morphism induces a natural transformation of the hom-functors. You don't need to add this as a condition here.

Write $Y$ as the disjoint union of its connected components; they are open by Stacks/04MF. Hence $Y$ is a coproduct of connected schemes. The rest is pure formal*.
By assumption for every such component $S$ of $Y$ there is some morphism $S \to X$ such that $S \to X \to Y$ is the inclusion. Glue them together. Then we get a morphism $g : Y \to X$ such that $fg=id_Y$.
Now consider the two morphisms $u=id_X$ and $v=gf$. They satisfy $fu=fv$, and we want to prove $u=v$.
So let more generally be $u,v : X' \to X$ be morphisms from a finite type scheme $X'$ with $fu=fv$. If $X'$ is connected, we are done by assumption. In general, again $X'$ is a coproduct of connected schemes $S$, and each time we have $f u|_S = f v|_S$. By the connected case, $u|_S = v|_S$, and thus $u=v$.
*In fact, more generally, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be a coproduct-dense subcategory, meaning every object in $\mathcal{C}$ is a coproduct of objects in $\mathcal{D}$. Then the restricted Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{D}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]$ is conversative. This means by definition that if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ such that for every $S \in \mathcal{D}$ the map $f_* : \hom(S,X) \to \hom(S,Y)$ is bijective, then $f$ is an isomorphism. The restricted Yoneda embedding is also faithful (for every colimit-dense subcategory), but notice that it is not full in this general setting, because for this we would need that $\mathcal{D}$ is a dense subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$. This is satisfied in the example with connected schemes above, actually, but it is a bit more than what we need to prove conservativity.

It might be helpful for a reader to note that one might summarize your argument (or a morally equivalent one) by saying $X$ and $Y$ are sheaves (e.g., for finite type $k$-schemes with the Zariski topology), and connected objects are a basis of this Grothendieck topology. So, any isomorphism between restrictions of sheaves to this basis uniquely extends to an isomorphism on the full category.

Thank you for your detailed answer! Could you please give examples of coproduct-dense subcategories of the category of $k$-schemes? In particular, is the subcategories $\mathcal{C}_a$ of affine $k$-schemes and $\mathcal{C}_f$ of $k$-schemes of finite type coproduct-dense?

For the category of all $k$-schemes, I don't believe that you can write down any interesting coproduct-dense subcategory. The examples you mention are definitely not coproduct-dense. The affine schemes are dense, though.

Dear @MartinBrandenburg, given that $Y$ is only locally of finite type, how can it be "a finite coproduct of connected schemes" ?

@mathfan24 Fixed.
